# InventoryScript error line 49 error CS1061

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory

So i have my code here, and unity Editor says -InventoryScript.cs(49,36): error CS1061: 'Item' does not contain a definition for 'item' and no accessible extension method 'item' accepting a first argument of type 'Item' could be found
I tryed already to fix it with chatgpt but still doesnt work

Line 49 is if (i.item == item.item)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventoryScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int money = 0; // current amount of money
    public int maxInventorySize = 20; // maximum number of items that can be carried
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>(); // list of all items in the inventory

    // UI elements for displaying inventory
    public GameObject inventoryUI;
    public Transform itemsParent;
    public GameObject itemSlotPrefab;

    private bool isInventoryOpen = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            isInventoryOpen = !isInventoryOpen;
            inventoryUI.SetActive(isInventoryOpen);
            Cursor.visible = isInventoryOpen;
            if (isInventoryOpen)
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0f; // pause the game
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1f; // resume the game
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && isInventoryOpen)
        {
            isInventoryOpen = false;
            inventoryUI.SetActive(false);
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Time.timeScale = 1f; // resume the game
        }
    }

    public bool AddItem(Item item)
    {
        if (item.stackable)
        {
            foreach (Item i in items)
            {
                if (i.item == item.item)
                {
                    i.quantity += item.quantity;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (items.Count < maxInventorySize)
        {
            items.Add(item);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void RemoveItem(Item item)
    {
        items.Remove(item);
    }

    public void DropItem(GameObject item)
    {
        Item itemComponent = item.GetComponent<Item>();
        if (itemComponent != null)
        {
            Instantiate(item, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            items.Remove(itemComponent);
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        inventoryUI.SetActive(false);
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        // Populate inventory UI with item slots
        for (int i = 0; i < maxInventorySize; i++)
        {
            GameObject slot = Instantiate(itemSlotPrefab, itemsParent);
        }
    }
}
```

i do not know what to do

Comment: And `Item` is? =) Can you please provide definition for this class?

Comment: Unless I read the code wrong, shouldn't you be comparing "i.item" to "items[i]" (or items[i].item) in the if statement? I.e 'if(i.item == items[i]) ---- But as @GuruStron mentioned, it would help to see the definition of the Item class, as it is not entirely clear what is being referenced without seeing the class :)